# Get old data in preUpdate Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I have a `product` entity and it has an `images` field that store the images names from the product but the images names depends of a `part_number` field that is unique, so if the user make a mistake in the part number and he wants to edit it then I also have to change the images names

I tried this but it does not works:

```
// class ProductsAdmin extends Admin

public function preUpdate($product) {

    $old_product = $this->getSubject();

    if ($old_product->getPartNumber() != $product->getPartNumber)
    {
         // change file names
    }

    $this->saveFile($product);
}
```

How I get the original row in preUpdate() function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the topic taken from the official SonataAdmin google forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-devs/0zML6N13i3U
you need to make use of the class UnitOfWork:
**http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html**

Do this way:

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    $em = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass());
    $original = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalDocumentData($object);
}
```

Thus you get an array of values of your database entity.
E.g: to get access to the value *password* of your entity do:

```
$password = $original['password'];
```

That's all.
Enjoy :)

Comment: Remember that for mongoDB you will use 'getOriginalDocumentData' as a method on the unitOfWork but for mysql you will need to use 'getOriginalEntityData'.

Answer (score 0):

If you just do a doctrine query in the preUpdate function to get the product from the database you'll have the old object. Then do the comparison and you're good to go.

Comment: Doctrine creators do not recommend use getUnitOfWork() as far as I remember. So this solution should be better