# SonataAdminBundle - check changes in `preUpdate` hook

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

Is it possible to check if field was changed on [`preUpdate`](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html#saving-hooks) hook? I'm looking for something like [`preUpdate`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) `hasChangedField($fieldName)` Doctrine functionality. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question is a bit similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095886/get-old-data-in-preupdate-sonata-admin-bundle/16148695)

Your solution is just to compare the field of the old object with the new one and see where it differs.

So for example:

```
public function preUpdate($newObject)
{
    $em = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass());
    $originalObject = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($newObject);

    if ($newObject->getSomeField() !== $originalObject['fieldName']) {
        // Field has been changed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! It was helpful. But this case should work for mongoDB (`getOriginalDocumentData`), for mysql I've used `getOriginalEntityData`. Additionally that function returns array, so I had to refer by `$originalObject['fieldName']`. It would be great if you could update your answer.

Comment: You were right I corrected my answer. Glad I could help!

Comment: Great answer but is there a way we can do this with postUpdate() ?

Answer (score 1):

For me the best approach is this in Sonata Admin:

```
$newField = $this->getForm()->get('field')->getData();
$oldField = $this->getForm()->get('field')->getConfig()->getData();
```

You shouldn't use unit of work unless there is no option. Also, if you have a not mapped field, you can't access it by entity object.

In a normal Doctrine lyfe cycle event, the best option is [Doctrine preupdate event doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks-event-argument)

Comment: for me $oldField is null