# doctrine detect new manytomany relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I create preupdate and prepersist event listener for doctrine. 
Have enity and i want check manytomany relation - is new or not.

```
task->tags
```

if tag is new do something

Comment: Have you tried comparing the new object to the old one (as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556895/sonataadminbundle-preupdate#21577417))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, Doctrine doesn't support preUpdate listener for association changes.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate