# Get old data in postUpdate Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

We know how to get the old data in Sonata's preUpdate hook, thanks to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21223387/3009025

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21577417/3009025

Does anyone know how to get this data in the postUpdate hook?

Answer (score 0):

in postUpdate this data is unsave but you can set one var in your class in preUpdate and get in postUpdate?

Comment: What do you mean "unsave"? Thanks for the idea but relying on state is not best practices. This data should be available on postUpdate imo.